# Negation (!) does not change the outcome of preg_match in PHP

Tags: php, preg-match, negation

When I apply a negation `!` to `preg_match`, I expect the result of the test to be reversed.  Yet this doesn't happen.

```
<?php

$text = '!SPQR! All roads lead to Rome!';

if (!preg_match('!SPQR!', $text) === 0) {echo 'Result A'."<br />";}
else{echo 'Result B'."<br />";}

if (preg_match('!SPQR!', $text) === 0) {echo 'Result A'."<br />";}
else{echo 'Result B'."<br />";}
```

Output:

> Result B
>
> Result B

Why does negation not reverse the outcome?

[Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) says:

> preg_match() returns 1 if the pattern matches given subject, 0 if it
>   does not, or FALSE if an error occurred.

[Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) also says to use `===` to test.

> Use the === operator for testing the return value of this function.

Comment: Use `==`,  `if ( !preg_match('!SPQR!', $text) == 0)`, not `===`. Or, `if ( preg_match('!SPQR!', $text) !== 0)`

Comment: `!` returns a boolean, you're comparing it to a number. And you're using strict equality, which doesn't do type juggling.

Comment: `!x === 0` is not the same as `x !== 0`.

Comment: First case: `preg_match` returns `1`, `!1` is `false`, `false` !== `0`. Second case: `preg_match` returns `1`, `1` !== `0`.

Comment: I thought that might be the case, but then why does the manual advise using `===` for this test?

Comment: Because `preg_match` can return `false` if an error occurs, and `0` if your pattern didn't match, so it lets you differentiate between them. Use `=== 1` to test if your pattern matched, since it's exactly what it returns then.